# Reactive UI ViewModelViewHost Performance in Visualizing ListView

Tags: mvvm, uwp, reactiveui

I'm investigating an issue with some performance in one of my UWP ListViews. This listview contains about 1000 items and the content of the listview item is injected via ReactiveUI's ViewModelHost.

It seems like when I remove the ViewModelHost and replace it with the actual control (i.e. not letting ReactiveUI determine which control to place) my performance increases dramatically.

My suspicion is that the content in the ViewModelHost is not being virtualized and is being re-created for every cell. Is this correct? Is ViewModelHost the recommended approach for listviews with large sets of data?